# Put point in string value (android java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, edit

I have BMI calculator app that takes some input and puts it in "EditText". Here is what I am trying to do:
If the input is `170`, it will become `1.70`.
If the input is `1.70`, it will not change.

This is the code I have:

```
String weight = editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you convert the string to an integer and take modulus 100 to the cms and divide by 100 to get in meters?

You can convert the String weight to int like this

```
int wgt = Integer.parseInt(weight);
```

Then separating meters and centimetres.

```
int mtrs = wgt / 100; 
int cms = wgt % 100;
```

Then combining both

```
String result = mtrs + "." + cms;
```

Comment: I am not understand.. Can you explain to me?

Comment: You can convert the `String weight` to int like this `int wgt = Integer.parseInt(weight);`

 `int mtrs = wgt / 100;`
`int cms = wgt % 100;`

`String result = mtrs + "." + cms;`

Comment: @דורעזרא is it working ? It should work.

Comment: I try , there are some problems here

Comment: @jgm Do you measure **weight** in centimeters?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
float value = Float.parse("170");
editText.setText(String.Format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%,02f", value/100f))
```

Comment: its say "cannot resolve method ׳parse(java.lang.String)׳"

Comment: it's called parseFloat, I should not develop in Chrome :-) http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)

Comment: and you have to add some if for example `if (value < 100) // don't divide  by 100`

Answer (score 0):

I found this way works: I take the number that the user put, and then  "170/100" + "0" gives me 1.70